# If a function $f: A \to \mathbb R$ is bounded and continuous on $A$, does its integral on said interval converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, bounded-variation

Let the bounded interval $A$ be a subset of the reals and let $f : A\to\mathbb R$ be a bounded and continuous function. Since the sequence $(f_n): f_n = f/n$ has the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = 0$, does the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_A \frac{f(x)}{n}\,\mathrm d x
\end{equation}
converge to zero as $n\to \infty?$

Comment: What does "converge uniformly" mean here?

Comment: Let me clarify, just a second.

Comment: This doesn't make too much sense. If $f$ is bounded, then of course $f/n\to 0.$ No need to say "if". There is no $n$ in the integral, and I still don't know what "converge uniformly" means here.

Comment: I just really really want the integral to disappear on the entire interval, if $n$ grows without bounds. Oh, I also edited the question once again.

Comment: It would be clearer if you state explicitly what "bounded interval $A$" in the real numbers is.  If $A=[a,b]$ is fixed (not dependent on $n$), then as other Comments point out, the factor $1/n$ comes outside the integral without any special difficulty.  Convergence of the (sequence of) integrals to zero is then obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple. Let $A= [a,b].$ Suppose $|f|\le M$ on $[a,b].$ Then

$$\left|\int_a^b (f/n)\right| \le \int_a^b |(f/n)| \le \int_a^b (1/n)M  = (1/n)M(b-a) \to 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{equation}
\int_A f(x)\,\mathrm d x \le \int_A \sup_x f(x) \, \mathrm d x \le \text{mes}(A) \cdot M < \infty,
\end{equation}
where $M := \sup_x f(x)$.

Comment: By the way, I assume $\mathrm{mes}(A)$ refers to the measure of $A$?

Comment: Yes, i wrote mes(A), since A could be any (bounded) union of intervals, not an interval itself

Comment: It seems this proof uses $f(x) \ge 0$.